# How can registered user can create a new article from joomla front-end in 2.5?

Tags: joomla

How to create a new article from joomla front-end by registered user. I tried a lot but i cant solves the problem.

Only super user can create a new article.
I create a new menu called create article in main menu and its access is gives to registered. But i still got the error

An error has occurred.
The requested page cannot be found.

Home Page
If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

## 403 You are not authorised to view this resource.

when i will try to create a new article by registered user from front-end.

Please help me for this.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 4):

By default registered users do not have create rights, you need to be an author for that.
You can do what you want in two ways, change the permission for Registered in com_content for Create to Allowed   or you could change the default user group for new users to Author.  YOu set the default group in the user manager options.

Answer (score 0):

The working of user role in joomla is something like this:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
    //print_r($user);
    //echo $user->get('gid');

    if($user->get('gid') == 25 ){

        //allow user
    } else{

        //disallow or redirect to somewhere

    }
```

The above code allows for user group 25 only.

What you need to do is:

Find the code for registered user and include the user group code in `if condition`.

Note: You can find the user group code from `jos_users` table.

Comment: Why not just use the built in ACL system?